# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty x^3 e^{-x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus

Surprisingly could not find the answer for this, since there a lot of posts floating around this website and elsewhere on evaluating $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx,$ which is not what I want. I just need a quick check on evaluating the following integral:

$$\int_0^\infty x^3 e^{-x^2}dx$$

I used a substitution and then integration by part. Need some help on checking if this approach is correct.

Let $u = - x^2$ so that $du = -2x dx$ and we can transform the integral as follows:

$$\lim_{B \to \infty} \int_0^B x^3 e^{-x^2} dx = \frac{1}{2}\lim_{B \to \infty} \int_{-B^2}^0 u e^u du.$$

Then we just evaluate the integral in terms of $u$ through integration by part. I think I got something like $-\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: I don't think you substituted properly. Wouldn't it still be $x^2ue^u$ as the integrand?

Comment: The answer is positive, as you can tell just by looking at the integrand. To reduce the power by $2$ you can integrate by parts with $dv=2xe^{-x^2},v=-e^{-x^2}$, where $u$ is the rest of the integrand. This reduces the problem to integrating $x e^{-x^2}$ which you already did in the first parts step. Anyway, your approach should still work if you carry it all out correctly (it essentially amounts to rewriting the integral in terms of the Gamma function and then computing the value of the Gamma function).

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E3e%5E-x%5E2
 $$-\frac1{2} e^{-x^2} (x^2+1)+constant $$